# Receiving error BC30201: Expression expected

Tags: vb.net, expression

```
    Catch ex As Exception
        GetTTCFTPini = {"Nothing"}
    End Try
```

it says at the

```
        GetTTCFTPini = {"Nothing"}
```

> error BC30201: Expression expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which version of Vb.Net are you using.  The array syntax you are using was added in VS 2010 (or possibly 2008) and won't work on older versions.  If that's the case then try the following instead

```
GetTTCFTPini = New Object() { "Nothing" }
```